# How to response cookie in Spring Boot without using HttpServletResponse?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I am looking for a better way to set cookie for response in Spring Boot.

After some search I've found two ways.

- Inject `HttpServletResponse` and use it `.addCookie` method. But it seems old fashioned servlet legacy.
- Use `ResponseEntity.header(HttpHeaders.SET_COOKIE, cookieString)`. This one would need to construct `cookieString` by self.

Is there other ways to set cookie in Spring Boot, or some way to construct cookie string?